# Call to fdopendir() corrupts file descriptor

Tags: c, linux

I stumbled upon a problem in a program I was working on. The following reproduces my issue:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, ret_fd;
    DIR *dirp;
    fd = open("./", O_RDONLY);

#if 1
    if ((dirp = fdopendir(fd)) == NULL) {
        perror("dirp");
        return 1;
    }
    closedir(dirp);
#endif

    ret_fd = openat(fd, "Makefile", O_RDONLY);
    if (ret_fd == -1) {
        perror("ret_fd");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Basically, the call to `openat()`, which has been preceeded by `fdopendir()`, fails with: `Bad file descriptor`. However, this does not happen if `fdopendir()` is omitted.

I know that `fdopendir()` makes internal use of the file descriptor, but shouldn't it revert any changes to it after calling `closedir()`?

What can I do to prevent `openat()` from failing in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [POSIX description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fdopendir.html) of `fdopendir()` says:

> Upon calling closedir() the file descriptor shall be closed.

So the descriptor is likely to be closed by the time you call `openat()`.

And this is from [a typical Linux man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man3/opendir.3.html) for `fdopendir():`

> After  a  successful  call to fdopendir(), fd is used internally by the
>   implementation, and should not otherwise be used by the application.

Comment: Note that to avoid this, you just need to `dup` the file descriptor before passing it to `fdopendir`.